# How to write empty or null byte to file?

Tags: php, text, byte

I need write empty bytes, or bytes that don't correspond to a valid character so that I can easily remove them later.

I am working with large files and when I remove something from the files I want to instead replace the text with empty bytes, and then remove them later. I can do this with `fseek` and then `fwrite` x number of empty bytes to the file, this way I don't need to re-write the entire file each time.  The problem is, if I overwrite the text using a valid character, then when I want to remove all the empty space from the file in the end, there is no way of knowing whether this character used is part of the file, or meant to be "empty space".  Is there any way to write "empty" data to the file, and then clean all the empty data of the file later?

Comment: doesn't something like `file_put_contents("","path/to/file")` work?

Comment: Empty bytes don't exit. Zero bytes exit. You write them as usual.

Comment: Bytes are regular numbers.  You need to design a file format that can unambiguously encode this information.  Good luck.

Comment: ummm `file_put_contents(chr(0),"path/to/file")`

Comment: there's no such thing as "empty" data. try filling the files with null bytes, e.g. hex 0x00. those are generally treated as eof-of-file markers in many languages and would be ignored, but still occupy space that you can overwrite/fill-in later.

Comment: fwrite(
    $fileHandle, 
    str_repeat(0x00, $repeatCount)
);

Answer (score 3):

Use null bytes (`\0`). These are often used as string terminators, so depending on how you read the resulting file you'll only get the text up to the first null byte, so be careful. The string functions in PHP are null-aware though so you'll be able to manipulate these strings.

```
fwrite($h, "\0");
```

If you need to write multiple nulls:

```
fwrite($h, str_repeat("\0", $number));
```